# START command doesn't work in neo4j 2.0 RC1..?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j 2.0 RC1. Problem comes from very simple command:

```
    START n=node:nodes(name = "A")
    RETURN n
```

But my Browser return: "Unknown error" like bellows picture

[image: Unknown error]

Could someone pls tell me how to fix this problem...??

Answer (score 3):

did you create and populate an index named "nodes" upfront? If you didn't and don't want to, go with

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.name = "A" RETURN n
```

or

```
MATCH (n:Label) WHERE n.name = "A" RETURN n
```

Comment: Dear @Michael Hunger

Yes, I did try it and got good result. But in official tutorial, I saw all cypher command begin with START. Because afraid about perfomance so I want to try with START command for specific Node.

Answer (score -1):

Start is depreciated in 2.0, though the tutorials might not all be updated yet to reflect it. Instead of Start, use Match:

```
Match (n:Label)
```

Comment: Start is not deprecated, it's still used to get node/rel by id or from legacy index (which is the case here)